# When Are Algebraic Numbers Algebraic Integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have started reading basics of analytic number theory. Meanwhile, I encountered [this blog post](https://expandingthemargin.wordpress.com/2021/02/04/when-are-algebraic-numbers-algebraic-integers/) which presents a sufficient criterion for an algebraic numbers to be algebraic integers. This theorem seems to be difficult to understand for a beginner. I want to know if there are other such criterions for algebraic numbers to be algebraic integers. When can we take the minimal polynomial to be monic and in $\Bbb{Z}[X]$?

Comment: I don’t think you really need to worry about such things right now. For example, in elementary number theory you usually do not need to know special criteria for rational numbers to be integers since you work directly with integers from the start, not rational numbers where it is unclear if they are integers.

Comment: In $\mathbf Q$, one way to show a nonzero rational number is an integer is to show it’s $p$-multiplicity is nonnegative for every prime $p$. That has an analogue for algebraic integers, using prime ideals, but this really is unlikely to be something relevant to you until you are far into a course on algebraic number theory.

Comment: Simul-posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383276/when-are-algebraic-numbers-algebraic-integers

Comment: If you know the number explicitly (I don’t mean its decimal expansion), then you can find its minimal polynomial over $\Bbb Q$. Then look at the coefficients.